# VisualSTudio run PostBuild event

Tags: visual-studio-2012, build

I want to run 2 post build events. I have separated the 2 commands by a full line break

**Build Command**

```
copy  "$(TargetDir)$(ProjectName).xap" "C:\www\Proj\ClientBin\MyXap.xap"

iexplore "http://localhost/MyProj"
```

But when I add this and press build I get `Exit code 9009.`

It looks like its trying to execute a full single sommand but they are 2 seperate commands

**The error from VS**

```
Error   1   The command "copy  "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Projects\MyXap\Bin\Debug\MyXap.xap" "C:\www\Proj\ClientBin\MyXap.xap"

iexplore "http://localhost/MyProj"" exited with code 9009.  MyXap
```

Comment: Post the content of the Output window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting Internet Explorer appears to be the problem.  At least two problems I saw, I needed to specify the full path and force the exit code to 0.  No real idea why any of this is necessary.  This test post-build event worked:

```
copy  "$(TargetDir)$(ProjectName).exe" "c:\temp\test.exe"
"c:\program files (x86)\internet explorer\iexplore" "http://stackoverflow.com"
exit /b 0
```

Do note that it is *very* unusual to write a post-build event like this.  It will only run if another file in the project requires recompilation.  So you won't get the browser running when you press F5 twice in a row.  This is very rarely desirable, favor using the Project + Properties, Debug tab, "Start external program" option instead.

Comment: I dont have the Start external program in my debug tab, is this because its a Silverlight project ? -

Comment: thankyou, this seemed to do the trick. What does the exit `/b 0` do ?

Comment: It forces the exit code back to 0, iexplore.exe returns 1 for some reason.